# Data driven(D3.js) vertical grouped bar chart with tooltip, clickable legends and brush facilities

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, brush, drilldown

I want to build a chart using D3.js using vertical bar chart on provided data and selected filters.

- Vertical grouped bar chart
- Legends
- Tooltip
- Brush and zoom
- Drill down

I have already added the filter for legends and tooltip, but facing issues while adding bursh. As i am new to D3, not sure what is the right way to integrate brush.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3-tip/0.7.1/d3-tip.min.js'></script>
</head>
<style>
    g.axis path, g.axis line {
        fill: none;
        stroke: black;
        shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    }

    g.brush rect.extent {
        fill-opacity: 0.2;
    }

    .resize path {
        fill-opacity: 0.2;
    }

    .n {
      opacity: .8;
      font-size: 10px;
      margin-left: 4px;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      color: white;
      padding: 6px;
      background-color: #3C3176;
    }
</style>
<body>

    <style>

        .axis .domain {
          display: none;
        }

        </style>
        <svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
        <script>

        var svg = d3.select("svg"),
            margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
            width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
            g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        // The scale spacing the groups:
        var x0 = d3.scaleBand()
            .rangeRound([0, width])
            .paddingInner(0.1);

        // The scale for spacing each group's bar:
        var x1 = d3.scaleBand()
            .padding(0.05);

        var y = d3.scaleLinear()
            .rangeRound([height, 0]);

        var z = d3.scaleOrdinal()
            .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

        d3.csv("data.csv", function(d, i, columns) {
          for (var i = 1, n = columns.length; i < n; ++i) d[columns[i]] = +d[columns[i]];
          return d;
        }, function(error, data) {
          if (error) throw error;

          var keys = data.columns.slice(1);

          const tip = d3.tip().html(d=> d.value);

          svg.call(tip);

          x0.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.State; }));
          x1.domain(keys).rangeRound([0, x0.bandwidth()]);
          y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d3.max(keys, function(key) { return d[key]; }); })]).nice();

         g.append("g")
            .selectAll("g")
            .data(data)
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class","bar")
            .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.State) + ",0)"; })
            .selectAll("rect")
            .data(function(d) { return keys.map(function(key) { return {key: key, value: d[key]}; }); })
            .enter().append("rect")
              .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.key); })
              .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
              .attr("width", x1.bandwidth())
              .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
              .attr("fill", function(d) { return z(d.key); })
              .on('mouseover', tip.show)
              .on('mouseout', tip.hide);

          g.append("g")
              .attr("class", "axis")
              .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
              .call(d3.axisBottom(x0));

          g.append("g")
              .attr("class", "y axis")
              .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(null, "s"))
            .append("text")
              .attr("x", 2)
              .attr("y", y(y.ticks().pop()) + 0.5)
              .attr("dy", "0.32em")
              .attr("fill", "#000")
              .attr("font-weight", "bold")
              .attr("text-anchor", "start")
              .text("Population");

         // Initialize brush component
          d3.brushX()
          .handleSize(10)
          .extent([10, 0], [g.width, g.height]);

          // Append brush component
         svg.append("g")
          .attr("class", "brush")
          .call(d3.brush);

          var legend = g.append("g")
              .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
              .attr("font-size", 10)
              .attr("text-anchor", "end")
            .selectAll("g")
            .data(keys.slice().reverse())
            .enter().append("g")
              .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

          legend.append("rect")
              .attr("x", width - 17)
              .attr("width", 15)
              .attr("height", 15)
              .attr("fill", z)
              .attr("stroke", z)
              .attr("stroke-width",2)
              .on("click",function(d) { update(d) });

          legend.append("text")
              .attr("x", width - 24)
              .attr("y", 9.5)
              .attr("dy", "0.32em")
              .text(function(d) { return d; });

          var filtered = [];

          ////
          //// Update and transition on click:
          ////

          function update(d) {  

            //
            // Update the array to filter the chart by:
            //

            // add the clicked key if not included:
            if (filtered.indexOf(d) == -1) {
             filtered.push(d); 
              // if all bars are un-checked, reset:
              if(filtered.length == keys.length) filtered = [];
            }
            // otherwise remove it:
            else {
              filtered.splice(filtered.indexOf(d), 1);
            }

            //
            // Update the scales for each group(/states)'s items:
            //
            var newKeys = [];
            keys.forEach(function(d) {
              if (filtered.indexOf(d) == -1 ) {
                newKeys.push(d);
              }
            })
            x1.domain(newKeys).rangeRound([0, x0.bandwidth()]);
            y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d3.max(keys, function(key) { if (filtered.indexOf(key) == -1) return d[key]; }); })]).nice();

            // update the y axis:
                    svg.select(".y")
                    .transition()
                    .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(null, "s"))
                    .duration(500);


            //
            // Filter out the bands that need to be hidden:
            //
            var bars = svg.selectAll(".bar").selectAll("rect")
              .data(function(d) { return keys.map(function(key) { return {key: key, value: d[key]}; }); })

           bars.filter(function(d) {
                 return filtered.indexOf(d.key) > -1;
              })
              .transition()
              .attr("x", function(d) {
                return (+d3.select(this).attr("x")) + (+d3.select(this).attr("width"))/2;  
              })
              .attr("height",0)
              .attr("width",0)     
              .attr("y", function(d) { return height; })
              .duration(500);

            //
            // Adjust the remaining bars:
            //
            bars.filter(function(d) {
                return filtered.indexOf(d.key) == -1;
              })
              .transition()
              .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.key); })
              .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
              .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
              .attr("width", x1.bandwidth())
              .attr("fill", function(d) { return z(d.key); })
              .duration(500);


            // update legend:
            legend.selectAll("rect")
              .transition()
              .attr("fill",function(d) {
                if (filtered.length) {
                  if (filtered.indexOf(d) == -1) {
                    return z(d); 
                  }
                   else {
                    return "white"; 
                  }
                }
                else {
                 return z(d); 
                }
              })
              .duration(100);


          }

        });

        </script>
```

```
State,Under 5 Years,5 to 13 Years,14 to 17 Years,18 to 24 Years,25 to 44 Years,45 to 64 Years,65 Years and Over
CA,2704659,4499890,2159981,3853788,10604510,8819342,4114496
TX,2027307,3277946,1420518,2454721,7017731,5656528,2472223
NY,1208495,2141490,1058031,1999120,5355235,5120254,2607672
FL,1140516,1938695,925060,1607297,4782119,4746856,3187797
IL,894368,1558919,725973,1311479,3596343,3239173,1575308
PA,737462,1345341,679201,1203944,3157759,3414001,1910571
```